# Visual Studio Entity Framework Viewer puts tables miles away

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

I have just reloaded my database model and added some new entities. Is there any way to ask Visual Studio to put the entities closer to the others in the designer by default?

See the below image to see what I mean:

[image: EF Viewer]